# how can send data from web to database in laravel

Tags: laravel

im beginner learn laravel,i made a 404 eror,how do i fix it please

code in web.php

```
route::post('/save-category','CategoryController@save_category')->name('save');
```

code in controller

```
 public function save_category(Request $request){
    $data=array();
    $data['category_id']=$request->category_id;
    $data['category_name']=$request->category_name;
    $data['category_description']=$request->category_description;
    $data['publication_status']=$request->publication_status;
    echo "<pre>";
     print_r($data);
    echo "<pre>";
```

code in view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BBd3.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Do not post code as images, no other users want to transcribe an image into code in order to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove the extra closing brace in the `action` attribute of your `form` element.
- If the controller is in the same domain, use `path()` which will generate an absolute path to instead of a full url

  ```
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ path('/save-category') }}" method="POST">
  ```

Comment: thank but it does not work (error Call to undefined function path() ) or patch

Comment: @tuanlinhvu where are you calling the path function?

Comment: it work,thank alots,i fix in web.php change post to patch

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you can use the route helper in the action attribute because you specified a name on the route

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('save') }}" method="POST">
```

Then to save it in your controller

```
 public function save_category(Request $request){
    Category::create([
       'category_id' => $request->category_id
       'category_name' => $request->category_name
       'category_description' => $request->category_description
       'publication_status' => $request->publication_status
    ])
 }
```

Then you need to create a model that is called Category which you can do by writing

> php artisan make:model Category

Then you will need a database table to represent the model,

> php artisan make:migration create_category_table

There is more info att
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#defining-models
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#generating-migrations